# Kivy softinput mode below_target does not work

Tags: android, python, kivy

I am writing a Kivy App for Android, originally when a textbox was selected, the keyboard would appear and cover up the text box.

So I found this parameter:

```
Window.softinput_mode = "below_target"
```

> When ‘below_target’, the window pans so that the current target TextInput widget requesting the keyboard is presented just above the soft Keyboard.

From

[Window - Kivy 1.9.1 Documentation](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.core.window.html#kivy.core.window.WindowBase.softinput_mode)

When I try to run this on my Windows machine and on the Android device, I get an error saying:

```
ValueError:  WindowSDL.softinput_mode is set to an invalid option 'below_target'
```

Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance,
Cooper

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `below_target` option was added more recently than the last stable release, which is Kivy 1.9. If you're running this version, you don't have it available yet.

You can use the master branch on android by just changing `kivy` to `kivy==master` in the buildozer requirements line.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying it, I look forward to the next version

Answer (score 1):

use this code before make MainApp(App)
and use kivy2.0.0

```
from kivy.core.window import Window
Window.keyboard_anim_args = {"d":.2,"t":"linear"}
Window.softinput_mode = "below_target"
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Please read the [tour] and [answer] While this code might solve the problem, adding explanation on how and why it does might be helpful, and will be better for a long term.